# Proving $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$ with elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation, determinant

I am trying to follow Artin's proof that $\det(AB) = \det(A) \det(B)$, but many of the details are omitted, so I am having difficulty.
I have established the following two lemmas.

> Lemma 1: $\det(EA) = \det(E) \det(A)$ for any elementary matrix $E$ and matrix $A$.
>
> Lemma 2: For an invertible matrix $A = E_1 E_2 \cdots E_n$, we have
> $$\det (A) = \det(E_1) \det(E_2) \cdots \det(E_n).$$

Artin uses these facts to conclude that
$$\det(AB) = \det(E_1 \cdots E_k B) = \det(E_1) \cdots \det(E_n) \det(B). $$
I do not understand why this result follows from the lemmas. Help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Induction. The basic result shows that $\det(E_n B) = \det E_n \det B$. Now repeat with $E_{n-1}$ and $E_n B$, etc.

Comment: Is $E_n$ a product of $n$ elementary matrices? If so, this makes complete sense.

Comment: I prefer to prove it by definition of determinant since it is more straightforward. $det(A)$ is ratio of $n$ - volume of an $n$ - dimensional body after and before undergoing transformation $A$. Since transformation $AB$ is transformation $B$ followed by transformation $A$, $det(AB)=det(A)det(B)$.

Comment: @JohnP.: Each $E_n$ is an elementary matrix and $E_1 \cdots E_n = A$.

Comment: Two excellent proofs  that det(AB) =det(A)det(B) can be found in this classic text. Algebra - A Text-Book of Determinants, Matrices, and Algebraic Forms  
by W. L. Ferrar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\det(AB) 
&= \det(\color{red}{E_1} \color{orange}{E_2} \color{blue}{E_3} \cdots E_k B)  \\
&= \det(\color{red}{E_1}) \det(\color{orange}{E_2} \color{blue}{E_3} \cdots E_k B) \tag{1} \\
&= \det(\color{red}{E_1}) \det(\color{orange}{E_2}) \det(\color{blue}{E_3} \cdots E_k B) \tag{2} \\
& \ \;   \vdots \\
&= \det(E_1) \det(E_2) \cdots \det(E_k) \det(B) \tag{$k$} \\
&= \det(A)\det(B) 
\end{align}$$
where in each of the steps $(1), (2), \dots, (k)$ we use lemma 1, since the $E_i$'s are elementary matrices; and in the last step we use lemma 2 assuming that $A = E_1\cdots E_k$.